# C Assembly Loop

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I'm a little confused on what is going on in this assembly. I can see the basics that if six numbers are not entered, the bomb will explode and end the program. Line by line, Its checking for input and entering a loop if the six numbers are non negative. I get lost here `0x0000000000400f29 <+29>:    add    -0x4(%rbp),%eax`.

It seems simple but I dont really understand whats being added here. Is it adding -4 and then comparing it to 0? Then jumping if equal?

I'm basically looking for clarification on the loop specifically, and what input pattern is expected to continue through the loop.

**Dump**

```
   0x0000000000400f0c <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400f0d <+1>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000000400f0e <+2>:     sub    $0x28,%rsp
   0x0000000000400f12 <+6>:     mov    %rsp,%rsi
   0x0000000000400f15 <+9>:     callq  0x40165a <read_six_numbers>
   0x0000000000400f1a <+14>:    cmpl   $0x0,(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400f1e <+18>:    jns    0x400f44 <phase_2+56>
   0x0000000000400f20 <+20>:    callq  0x401624 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000400f25 <+25>:    jmp    0x400f44 <phase_2+56>
   0x0000000000400f27 <+27>:    mov    %ebx,%eax
=> 0x0000000000400f29 <+29>:    add    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400f2c <+32>:    cmp    %eax,0x0(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400f2f <+35>:    je     0x400f36 <phase_2+42>
   0x0000000000400f31 <+37>:    callq  0x401624 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000400f36 <+42>:    add    $0x1,%ebx
   0x0000000000400f39 <+45>:    add    $0x4,%rbp
   0x0000000000400f3d <+49>:    cmp    $0x6,%ebx
   0x0000000000400f40 <+52>:    jne    0x400f27 <phase_2+27>
   0x0000000000400f42 <+54>:    jmp    0x400f50 <phase_2+68>
   0x0000000000400f44 <+56>:    lea    0x4(%rsp),%rbp
   0x0000000000400f49 <+61>:    mov    $0x1,%ebx
   0x0000000000400f4e <+66>:    jmp    0x400f27 <phase_2+27>
   0x0000000000400f50 <+68>:    add    $0x28,%rsp
   0x0000000000400f54 <+72>:    pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000400f55 <+73>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000400f56 <+74>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

**read_six_numbers**

```
Dump of assembler code for function read_six_numbers:
=> 0x000000000040165a <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000000000040165e <+4>:     mov    %rsi,%rdx
   0x0000000000401661 <+7>:     lea    0x4(%rsi),%rcx
   0x0000000000401665 <+11>:    lea    0x14(%rsi),%rax
   0x0000000000401669 <+15>:    mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x000000000040166e <+20>:    lea    0x10(%rsi),%rax
   0x0000000000401672 <+24>:    mov    %rax,(%rsp)
   0x0000000000401676 <+28>:    lea    0xc(%rsi),%r9
   0x000000000040167a <+32>:    lea    0x8(%rsi),%r8
   0x000000000040167e <+36>:    mov    $0x402871,%esi
   0x0000000000401683 <+41>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401688 <+46>:    callq  0x400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x000000000040168d <+51>:    cmp    $0x5,%eax
   0x0000000000401690 <+54>:    jg     0x401697 <read_six_numbers+61>
   0x0000000000401692 <+56>:    callq  0x401624 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401697 <+61>:    add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000000000040169b <+65>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: which part is `C`?

Comment: It is adding the value in memory location pointed to by `rbp-4` to `eax`, then comparing `eax` to the value in memory at location `rbp`

Comment: Would it not be correct to say this is the assembly generated in response to the `C` code?

Comment: I do not see anything in the syntax of the C language in the question, or any mentioning of C. Why is the C tag there? Would you like to show the C code which is the source of this assembly? If that is the case.

Comment: The idiotic AT&T syntax is confounding as always. `add -0x4(%rbp),%eax` is `add eax, [rbp-4]` in Intel syntax, which means "add to eax the value stored at rbp-4" (in pseudo C it would be something like `eax+=*((uint32_t *)rbp-1)` - -1 and not -4 because of how pointer arithmetic work in C). Long story short, it is just adding to eax the value of a local variable (remember: as a rule of thumb, rbp+something are parameters on the stack, rbp-something are locals).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding ATT Assembly Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915791/understanding-att-assembly-language)

Comment: @MatteoItalia Is it possible to tell what input pattern is expected based purely off the assembly, or will it take some deeper inspection of the registers to figure out?

Comment: Seeing the code of `read_six_numbers` would be helpful. OTOH I may as well look back into my answers history for it, I have the distinct memory of having already replied to one of these "bomb explosion" questions, maybe this is exactly the same.

Comment: @MatteoItalia the code is not provided. Theres hundreds of different iterations of these same problems. Varying in difficulty. I've gone through the easier ones, where its something easy like just double each of the 6 numbers. Maybe I'm just missing something but can't seem to figure out what's expected for the 6 numbers in this scenario. Appreciate the help.

Comment: For "code" I mean assembly of course. Still, it's actually quite clear, it receives a pointer to a local buffer into rsi and probably writes the six digits in there. Still, there's something fishy about rbp, I wanted to check what happens to it into that function call.

Comment: @MatteoItalia added the assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a cursory read, the whole thing boils down to:

```
void read_six_numbers(const char *sz, int numbers[6]) {
    // the format string is inferred from the context,
    // to see its actual value you should look at 0x402871
    if(sscanf(sz, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &numbers[0], &numbers[1], &numbers[2], &numbers[3], &numbers[4], &numbers[5])<6) explode_bomb();
}

void phase_2(const char *sz) {
    int numbers[6];
    read_six_numbers(sz, numbers);
    if(numbers[0] < 0) explode_bomb();
    for(int i=1; i!=6; ++i) {
        int a = i + numbers[i-1];
        if(numbers[i]!=a) explode_bomb();
    }
}
```

<del>Unfortunately at the moment I'm on a train with no PC and limited time, later I'll add a detailed explanation.</del> Here it comes!

> ***Notice***: through this post I'll use the Intel notation for assembly; it's different than what you posted, but, at least IMO, it's way more readable and understandable - besides the terrible taste for sigils in AT&T notation, the reversed operands make zero sense in many instructions, especially arithmetic ones and `cmp`; also, the syntax for memory addressing is downright unreadable.

---

### `read_six_numbers`

Let's start from the easy one - `read_six_numbers`; as you can see from the code in `phase_2`

```
<+6>:     mov    rsi,rsp
<+9>:     call   0x40165a <read_six_numbers>
```

it receives a parameter in `rsi`, and it's a pointer to something on the caller's stack. The regular SystemV calling convention uses `rsi` for the *second* parameter, and `read_six_numbers` reads `rdi` (implicitly, we'll see later). So we can assume that `phase_2` does receive a parameter in `rdi` and leaves it there, passing it straight to `read_six_numbers`.

After a "classic" prologue where it reserves stack for locals

```
<+0>:     sub    rsp,0x18
```

it proceeds to load "adjusted" pointer values into various registers and on the stack

```
<+4>:     mov    rdx,rsi
<+7>:     lea    rcx,[rsi+0x4]
<+11>:    lea    rax,[rsi+0x14]
<+15>:    mov    [rsp+0x8],rax
<+20>:    lea    rax,[rsi+0x10]
<+24>:    mov    [rsp],rax
<+28>:    lea    r9,[rsi+0xc]
<+32>:    lea    r8,[rsi+0x8]
```

If you follow the code, you'll see that the end result is

```
rdx     <- rsi
rcx     <- rsi+4
r8      <- rsi+8
r9      <- rsi+12
[rsp]   <- rsi+16
[rsp+8] <- rsi+20
```

(don't let the `lea` fool you - although in the `[]` syntax would make you think that it's accessing the memory at the address inside the brackets, it's actually just copying that address to the operand on the left)

Then

```
<+36>:    mov    esi,0x402871
<+41>:    mov    eax,0x0
<+46>:    call   0x400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
```

`rsi` is now set to some fixed address<sup>1</sup>, which looks really like a string literal or a global, given its address and the fact that it's in `rsi` (so it's going to be the second argument to the `sscanf` below).

So, this is [a regular x86_64 System V ABI variadic call](http://blog.afa.moe/201412/varargs_calling_conv/#x86_64_(gcc_4-7-2,_System_V_ABI)) to `sscanf`<sup>2</sup> - which requires arguments to passed (in order) into `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8`, `r9`, and the rest on the stack, and `ax` set to the number of floating point arguments stored in the XMM registers (here zero, hence that `mov`<sup>3</sup>).

If we put together the pieces we gathered until now we can deduce that:

- `rdi` is a `const char *`, and is the source string for the six numbers to be read;
- `rsi` contains a pointer to an array of at least six `int` (see that it loads the registers with offset 4 - AKA `sizeof(int)`?), which are read from the string in `rdi`;
- most probably, if we look at `0x402871` we'll see something like `"%d %d %d %d %d %d"`.

So, we can start to write a tentative definition of this function:

```
void read_six_numbers(const char *sz, int numbers[6]) {
    int eax = sscanf(sz, "%d %d %d %d %d %d",
            &numbers[0], &numbers[1], &numbers[2],
            &numbers[3], &numbers[4], &numbers[5]);
    ...
}
```

Notice that here I wrote `numbers[6]` only as a reminder for me, for the C language the size in array parameters is ignored - it's just a regular pointer; also, I wrote `void` as return type because I see that in the calling code nobody seems interested in `rax` or `eax` after calling this function.

Then:

```
<+51>:    cmp    eax,0x5
<+54>:    jg     0x401697 <read_six_numbers+61>
<+56>:    call   0x401624 <explode_bomb>
<+61>:    add    rsp,0x18
<+65>:    ret
```

Here it's just checking if the value returned by `sscanf` is greater than 5 - i.e. if it managed to read all the required fields; if it is, it jumps over a call to `explode_bomb`. We could rewrite this in a more human-friendly way like

```
if(eax<6) explode_bomb();
```

Then, at +61 and +65 there's the standard function epilogue (fix up the stack and return).

So, all in all we can write the whole thing as

```
void read_six_numbers(const char *sz, int numbers[6]) {
    if(sscanf(sz, "%d %d %d %d %d %d",
            &numbers[0], &numbers[1], &numbers[2],
            &numbers[3], &numbers[4], &numbers[5] < 6) {
        explode_bomb();
    }
}
```

and call it a day.

---

### `phase_2`

```
<+0>:     push   rbp
<+1>:     push   rbx
<+2>:     sub    rsp,0x28
```

Usual prologue; 40 bytes of local variables, save `rbp` and `rbx` because they are going to be used (and both are callee-saved register); notice that here `rbp` is *not* used as stack frame pointer, but as a "regular" register.

```
<+6>:     mov    rsi,rsp
<+9>:     call   0x40165a <read_six_numbers>
```

Call `read_six_numbers`, implicitly forwarding the first parameter of `pase_2` as first parameter or `read_six_numbers` in `rdi` (which we gathered is the string that has to be parsed), and passing the top of the stack as the `numbers` parameter.

Remember that the stack grows *downwards* (=> towards smaller addresses), while array elements go *upwards* (=> towards bigger addresses), so passing `rsp` as pointer to the first array element means that the following elements are correctly in the portion of stack that has just been allocated with the `sub` above.

From now on, remember that `rsp` points to the first element of the `numbers` array.

```
<+14>:    cmp    [rsp],0
<+18>:    jns    0x400f44 <phase_2+56>
<+20>:    call  0x401624 <explode_bomb>
<+25>:    jmp    0x400f44 <phase_2+56>
```

Check if the first number (`[rsp]` <=> `*numbers` <=> `numbers[0]`) is not negative; if so, skip the call to `explode_bomb`.

(to understand how it works, remember that `cmp` performs a subtraction without saving the result, but only the flags corresponding to it, so `[rsp]-0` is plain `[rsp]`, and `jns` means *j*ump if *n*ot *s*ign bit, so it jumps if the result of the `cmp` is non-negative)

Let's try to speculate what we have until now:

```
ret_type? phase_2(const char *sz) {
    int numbers[6];
    read_six_numbers(sz, numbers);
    if(numbers[0]<0) explode_bomb();
    ...
}
```

Let's skip the part between +27 and +56 for now, and go on with the regular control flow - straight to +56:

```
<+56>:    lea    rbp,[rsp+4]
<+61>:    mov    ebx,1
<+66>:    jmp    0x400f27 <phase_2+27>
```

Here it loads `rbp` with `&numbers[1]` (remember that each element of `numbers` is 4 bytes big) and `ebx` with `1`, then, it jumps back to +27.

```
<+27>:    mov    eax,ebx
<+29>:    add    eax,[rbp-4]
<+32>:    cmp    [rbp],eax
<+35>:    je     0x400f36 <phase_2+42>
<+37>:    call   0x401624 <explode_bomb>
<+42>:    add    ebx,1
<+45>:    add    rbp,4
<+49>:    cmp    ebx,6
<+52>:    jne    0x400f27 <phase_2+27>
<+54>:    jmp    0x400f50 <phase_2+68>
```

If you have a quick look around into the jumps, you'll see that:

- the small block at +56 is never executed again;
- the bigger block between [+27, +56), where we jump after this small block, is conditionally repeated (see the `jne` at `+52`)

This is a good hint that this is something like a `for` loop, where the small block above is the initialization, the section before the jump the check of the condition and those `add` an increment. `ebx`, which is initialized (+61), incremented (+42) and checked (+49), surely looks like a counter variable.

We'll get back to this; for now, let's go on with the loop body:

```
<+27>:    mov    eax,ebx
<+29>:    add    eax,[rbp-4]
<+32>:    cmp    [rbp],eax
<+35>:    je     0x400f36 <phase_2+42>
<+37>:    call   0x401624 <explode_bomb>
```

Copy the loop counter into `eax`, and then add to it the value in the array element *before* (`-4`) the one that was pointed by `rbp`. Then, it is compared with the element *currently pointed* by `rbp`, and the bomb is made explode if they don't match.

```
<+42>:    add    ebx,1
<+45>:    add    rbp,4
```

The loop counter (`ebx`) is incremented, `rbp` is moved on to the next `numbers` element (increment phase)

```
<+49>:    cmp    ebx,6
<+52>:    jne    0x400f27 <phase_2+27>
<+54>:    jmp    0x400f50 <phase_2+68>
```

If the loop counter didn't reach 6 (the numbers of elements in the `numbers` array) yet, rinse and repeat, otherwise jump to the end of the function.

```
<+68>:    add    rsp,0x28
<+72>:    pop    rbx
<+73>:    pop    rbp
<+74>:    ret
```

Usual cleanup: deallocate the locals, restore the clobbered registers, return.

Let's try to sum it up:

```
void phase_2(const char *sz) {
    int numbers[6];
    read_six_numbers(sz, numbers);
    if(numbers[0]<0) explode_bomb();
    int ebx = 1;
    int *rbp = &numbers[1];
    do {
        int eax = ebx + rbp[-1];
        if(eax != rbp[0]) explode_bomb();
        ++ebx;
        ++rbp;
    } while(ebx!=6);
}
```

This isn't really how a C programmer would write it; that `do`...`while`, although a direct translation of the assembly, is quite innatural for a C programmer (although checking the condition just before looping is instead more natural to write in assembly).

Also, all those games with `rbp` are just an artifact of the optimizer, which avoids recomputing the target address from the index by "moving on" both `ebx` and `rbp`. All in all, it was probably written more like:

```
void phase_2(const char *sz) {
    int numbers[6];
    read_six_numbers(sz, numbers);
    if(numbers[0]<0) explode_bomb();
    for(int i=1; i<6; ++i) {
        int n = i + numbers[i-1];
        if(n != numbers[i]) explode_bomb();
    }
}
```

... and there we are.

As a final check, we can re-run the compiler over this, if it was a well-known one it will proably produce back the same assembly.

... and in facts, that's [the exact assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/qm0esy) generated by gcc 4.9 (and other versions) at `-O1`.

Interestingly, moving the optimization level at `-O2`, it changes the `mov eax,0` commented in note 3 to `xor eax,eax`, so it was probably just the result of sloppy optimizer work at lower optimization level.

---

#### Notes

1. Actually it uses `esi`, but the result is as described - the top 32 bits of that address are zero anyway, and setting the 32-bit portion of a 64 bit register zeroes out the register top 32 bit. It *is* possible to do a `mov r64,imm64` (in facts it's one of the few cases where you can actually have an imm64 value), but it's a huge instrution for no gain here.
2. The `__isoc99` part is probably to disambiguate between various versions of `sscanf` used to support various C standard revisions, or to avoid conflicts/confusions with the `sscanf` exported by older, non-C99 compatible versions of `libc`; the `plt` thing is an intermediate trampoline used to resolve functions imported from shared libaries.
3. It's still a bit unusual that zeroing out the `eax` register is done through a huge 5-byte `mov` - generally, it's done through the more compact 2-byte `xor eax,eax`; I don't know if there's some particular reason why the compiler chose this encoding - maybe it preferred to use a 5-byte `move` and keep aligned the `call` instead of using a 2-byte `xor` and then a `nop` to align the `call` to 4 bytes, maybe it's just that this is a canned sequence that is not touched by the optimizer. ***Edit***: given that, enabling higher optimizer levels, it becomes `xor eax,eax`, I'd say that it's just an optimizer blooper (or maybe at higher optimization levels even those canned sequences go through the peephole optimizer).

Comment: I will read your detailed explanation in the morning. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No. The first must not be negative, the others must be equal to the previous one + their index - so, for example, the element3 (=the fourth number) must be equal to element2 + 3. Incidentally, as you can see I wrote the step by step explanation.

Comment: Wow. Wasn't expecting that explanation. Great work, and I did figure out the sequence - 0 1 3 6 10 15. Just misread the loop. Looking forward to reading your explanation.